# How to load "Hello World" into the `.data` section in WebAssembly wast

Tags: string, webassembly

I am looking at the [WebAssembly tests](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/data.wast), and seeing this for `data`:

```
(module
  (memory $m 1)
  (data (i32.const 0))
  (data (i32.const 1) "a" "" "bcd")
  (data (offset (i32.const 0)))
  (data (offset (i32.const 0)) "" "a" "bc" "")
  (data 0 (i32.const 0))
  (data 0x0 (i32.const 1) "a" "" "bcd")
  (data 0x000 (offset (i32.const 0)))
  (data 0 (offset (i32.const 0)) "" "a" "bc" "")
  (data $m (i32.const 0))
  (data $m (i32.const 1) "a" "" "bcd")
  (data $m (offset (i32.const 0)))
  (data $m (offset (i32.const 0)) "" "a" "bc" "")
)
```

Wondering what it would look like to place "Hello World" into `data` section. I am new to this low-level functionality. Something like:

```
(data "Hello World")
```

In x86 assembly you can do:

```
message:  db "Hello, World", 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a definition for the [data segment syntax](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/modules.html#data-segments) within the [WebAssembly Text Format specification](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/index.html). It is really quite straightforward, here is is in a simpler form:

`data $memidx $offset $data`

Where `$memidx` is an optional index that indicates which module memory the data segment populates. In the current version of WebAssembly only a [single module memory](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/modules.html#memories) is supported, so this will always be zero.

The `$offset` is a constant expression that indicates the start location where the data should be written.

Finally `$data` is the data itself. It can represent textual or binary data, with a simple encoding as [detailed in the specification](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/values.html#strings).

For your example, to add `Hello World` to module memory at an offset of zero this will do the job:

`(data (i32.const 0) "Hello World")`

Comment: Giving this error: `error: memory variable out of range (max 0)
(module (data (i32.const 0) "Hello World"))
         ^^^^` Fixed by adding `(module (memory $m 1) (data (i32.const 0) "Hello World"))`